# multiple values from select and active record with ' where in'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, html-select

I am stuck in a problem, which i am unable to resolve. I have a select tag as follows:

```
select_tag :interest,options_from_collection_for_select(@InterestAreas, "id", 
"InterestArea"),{:prompt => "Interest Area",  :multiple => true}
```

as you can see, i have `:multiple => true` which will allow me to select the values.

With these selected values i want to run an active record query as follows:

```
@user = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['((?) is null or "users"."interest" in (?))',
interest,interest])
```

with selecting single value it is working fine. but when i provide multiple values from selection it gives following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
((('2','4') is null or "users"."interest" in ('2','4')))
```

It is related to hash i think. But i am not sure what should i do. should i convert it before i pass it in active record parameter. Plz Suggest.

Regards

Comment: `((?) is null` what attribute do you want to give here?

Comment: actually i have many AND clauses. if any value is null, it will go for other AND clause.

Comment: Oops! Misjudged your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this: https://gist.github.com/wakiki/3312792

And after use this:

```
@user = User.where(interest: params[:interest]).or.where(interest: nil)
```